# How to pronounce the symbol “~”

Tags: meaning, symbols

Saw this electrical engineer formula in regards to a low voltage charge controller:
5 ~ (15W * #(4~8)) *3

What do I call the “~”
(means approximate I think)

What does this formula mean to a lay person?

Comment: One part of this question may be general reference, but it's unclear what you are asking about the formula as it relates to the English language.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].

Comment: Of course a Unix guy would pronounce it *twiddle* or *squiggle*.

Comment: Yeah, I pronounce it "twiddle".

Comment: In electrical engineering terms, your formula looks like gibberish. If you could provide a link to the source, that would help. In the simple expression "the current is ~4 A", I would pronounce it as "the current is approximately 4 amps."

Comment: A wavy line similar to a tilde is often used for alternating current (AC). [See e.g. here](https://www.electrical-symbols.com/electric-electronic-symbols/electric-current-symbols.htm). This is a question about electrical engineering/electronics, not the English langauge.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the English language, but is about symbols used in electrical engineering. There is https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ but it expects better questions (provide references, list research, check the question is on topic).

Comment: For the "name" of a character, perhaps find it in Unicode ... U+007E is described as TILDE.

Comment: A single tilde preceding a number indicates approximation, as Jack noted. It can also be pronounced as "about", e.g. "about four amps". A tilde between two numbers indicates a range, often pronounced as "to". So 5 ~ 15 W would be read as "five to fifteen watts". (I'm an electrical engineer.)

Answer (score 2):

The symbol is called a "tilde". The word "tilde" comes from the Latin word "titulus", meaning "title" or "superscription", and would be pronounced til-duh, or /ˈtɪldə/, in most varieties of American English.

Comment: One or more hyperlinks to source(s) for the etymology you provide would be a nice addition to this answer.